# How to check a Zenon-generated proof with Coq?

Tags: coq, zenon

I installed zenon ([opam package](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/zenon/), [github](https://github.com/zenon-prover/zenon)) and tried to use it to generate a Coq proof.

I couldn't find any documentation for the Zenon's main syntax, so I looked at its test suite.

I grabbed [this test](https://github.com/zenon-prover/zenon/blob/9c17eae28ce6acaf7f3bc91af25e395b423316db/test/test01.znn) out of its test suite.

```
$sig P ("nat") "Prop"
$sig Q ("nat") "Prop"

$hyp "h1" (A. ((x "nat") (P x)))
$hyp "h2" (A. ((x "nat") (Q x)))
$goal (-. (\/ (A. ((x "nat") (-. (Q x)))) (A. ((x "nat") (-. (P x))))))
```

`zenon -ocoq test01.znn` produces the following output.

```
(* PROOF-FOUND *)                                            
(* BEGIN-PROOF *)
Theorem zenon_thm : (~((forall x : nat, (~(Q x)))\/(forall x : nat, (~(P x))))).
Proof.
apply NNPP. intro zenon_G.
apply zenon_G. zenon_intro zenon_H3.
apply (zenon_or_s _ _ zenon_H3); [ zenon_intro zenon_H5 | zenon_intro zenon_H4 ].
generalize (h2 O). zenon_intro zenon_H6.
generalize (zenon_H5 O). zenon_intro zenon_H7.
exact (zenon_H7 zenon_H6).
generalize (h1 O). zenon_intro zenon_H8.
generalize (zenon_H4 O). zenon_intro zenon_H9.
exact (zenon_H9 zenon_H8).
Qed.
(* END-PROOF *)
```

I wrote the above to `test01.v` and tried to compile that into a `.vo` file.

```
coqc test01.v
File "./test01.v", line 3, characters 43-44:
Error: The reference Q was not found in the current environment.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. `P` and `Q` are both defined in the `znn` file.

Here are the versions of Coq and Zenon involved:

```
zenon -v
zenon version 0.8.5 [a270] 2020-10-23
```

```
coqc -v
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.16.1
compiled with OCaml 4.11.1
```